# Upgrading to Entity Framework from Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Although I have been through a number of posts that discuss Linq to SQL and Entity Framework there still exists a lot of confusion at this stage about the following questions.

Before I mention the questions let me say that I have completed a desktop application using Linq to SQL and this usage is based purely on mapping and using SPROCS.

1. Do I need to upgrade or rewrite my CRUD operations to using Entity Framework? If so what are the advantages that I will have using entity framework over Linq to SQL with SPROCS?
2. Is Entity framework supported by Visual Studio 2008 / .net framework 3.5?
3. What are the differences between Entity Framework support in .net 3.5 and 4.0?

These are just a few of the questions that I need some help with before I form a complete picture of the scenario.

If any of you out there have any useful insights that you can provide I would appreciate it

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: This isn't a question that can really be answered here, the answers are too large to post here.

Comment: Well there is just one question that may have a large number of answers. Question no 3. As it is I am more concerned with answers to 1 & 2... The differences I can find on my own :-)

Comment: Guys! At least let me know which part of my question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete or rhetorical? I can understand that the answers to a part of my question or one of my questions is overly broad. I have already acknowledged that. But the fact is that the answers that I have received make sense. So how can the questions be vague or ambitious! Don't you think you guys are being judgmental ? I would expect some objectivity to your ahem rulings! (for want of a better word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No; if your architecture uses stored procedures for all CRUD operations, then you can reuse them with the Entity Framework. Note that EF1 (.NET 3.5) did not support `OUTPUT` parameters, so you'll want to keep that in mind if that makes a difference to you. Just bear in mind that you lose a lot of the flexibility of an ORM when you constrain it to using stored procedures only.
2. Yes
3. They are almost different products. EF1 (.NET 3.5) is regarded by many people (myself included) as not fit for production use. There are a lot of gotchas, not the least of which being the fact that you essentially have to choose between navigation properties and having the actual foreign key value on your entity types. There are workarounds, but they're not pretty.

EF4 is *lightyears* better than EF1. We're using EF4 in our production system and it works quite well. The specific differences are almost too many to list, but the upshot is that you should strongly consider either upgrading to .NET 4.0 or *not* using the Entity Framework. EF1 is just that bad.

Comment: Yeh, do not use EF1, its a alpha from EF4 that came out as a release.

Comment: Another big gotcha between LINQ to SQL and EF is the lazy loading behavior differences (which are also different between 1 and 4). In general EF 4 reacts more like L2S in numbers of ways, but I agree if your data layer is currently working, you need a good business justification to making the shift.

Comment: Just to be accurate regarding question 2, VS2008/.NET 3.5 _does not_ support the Entity Framework. Only VS2008 SP1/.NET 3.5 SP1 supports it.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - L2S is not end of lifed.  Where did you get that information?

Comment: Thanks Adam for a brief and very helpful answer.